# Mysql query extracting date + group by day

Tags: mysql, sql

Simple question: Why does the following query not output `perday`?

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`,"%Y-%m-%d") AS `perday`, COUNT(*) AS `count` 
FROM `data` 
WHERE `group` = 1
GROUP BY `perday`
```

Count gets outputted correctly, but `perday` stays empty.
The `data` table is like:

```
 |   id   |   group   |          date          |
------------------------------------------------
 |   1    |     1     |  2013-04-13 06:01:02   |
 |   2    |     1     |  2013-04-13 14:24:18   |
 |   3    |     2     |  2012-01-21 21:33:03   |
              Ect.
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Expected output:

```
 |   perday   |
 --------------
 | 2013-04-13 |
 | 2012-01-21 |
```

Comment: What output would you expect exactly?

Comment: i put the expected result in the edit... And why the downvote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

remove `WHERE` clause,

```
SELECT  FROM_UNIXTIME(date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS perday, 
        SUM(`group` = 1)  AS `count` 
FROM    data 
GROUP   BY FROM_UNIXTIME(date,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

if date is formatted as `2013-04-13 06:01:02`, then why use `FROM_UNIXTIME`? Isn't it `DATE_FORMAT` instead?

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS perday, 
        SUM(`group` = 1)  AS `count` 
FROM    data 
GROUP   BY DATE(date)
ORDER   BY date
```

This will display all available dates in the table.

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f89bb/2)

But if you want the selected `group` only,

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS perday, 
        COUNT(*)  AS `count` 
FROM    data 
WHERE   `group` = 1
GROUP   BY DATE(date)
ORDER   BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

you may looking for this

```
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`,"%Y-%m-%d") AS `perday`, COUNT(*) AS `count` 
    FROM `data` 
    WHERE `group` = 1
    GROUP BY `perday`
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f1dd/4)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL `DATE()` takes the DATE part out from a `DATETIME` expression.As your `Expected output` this query is fine.

```
SELECT
  DATE(`date`) AS `perday`,
  COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM `data`
GROUP BY `perday`
```